# How to target input value and remove text in IE7

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have an `input` field for a submit button:

```
<input id="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

In `CSS` I put a background image over the button to look like a magnify glass instead of the default button.

This works in most browsers but I am having problems with IE 7 and the `value` text showing over the top of the image.

Is there a simple way to get rid of this text without removing it from the `value` field of the `input` element?  Something to the effect of:

```
#searchSubmit input[type="submit"][value=Search] {
    text-indent:-999em !important;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this simple but elegant workaround to your css.

> Negative-indent alone unfortunately doesn't work to remove text from a button element in IE7, but add text-transform: capitalize; and presto!

```
#searchSubmit {
     text-indent: -9000px;
     text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-button-text-in-ie7/

Answer (score 1):

Set the font size to ZERO. The ***** prefix will target IE7 (and six).

```
#searchSubmit  {
    *font-size:0;
    *width:50px;
    *height:22px;
}​
```

You need to specify a width and height for this to work because the button is sized based on the text.

Also in CSS, if an item has an ID, you don't need any secondary selectors:

```
#searchSubmit {...}
```

not:

```
#searchSubmit input[type="submit"][value=Search] {...}
```